# ckeditor not updating textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor and according to the [documentation](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/savetextarea.html) the textarea value should be updated automatically. However, it is not.

This is the JS I am using:

```
  ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#usp-content' ), {
        toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList' ]
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.log( error );
    } );
```

And this is the html:

```
   <form id="usp-form-11>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea name="usp-content" id="usp-content" rows="5" cols="30" maxlength="999999" data-required="true" required="required" placeholder="Type something..." class="usp-input usp-textarea usp-input-content my_content form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
   </form>
```

But when I submit I get

> An invalid form control with name='usp-content' is not focusable.

I even tried to add the following even tho the documentation says it should do it automatically:

```
var contents = $('.ck-content').html();
$('.ck-content').blur(function() {
  if (contents!=$(this).html()){
    contents = $(this).html();
  }
});

$("#usp-form-11").on("submit", function(){
  $("#usp-content").attr("value", contents);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by grabbing the data manually and placing as the textarea value on submit

```
document.querySelector( '.usp-submit' ).addEventListener( 'click', () => {
  const editorData = editor.getData();
  jQuery("#usp-content").val(editorData);
} );
```

[It is also on their doc](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/saving-data.html)